# Assign columns to datatable when it is null

Tags: c#, datatable

Hi all I am declaring my datatable as `DataTable dt=null` I would like to add columns to this datatable with out declaring it as `dt=new DataTable();` is it possible to do this

Comment: Can you perhaps explain why you need to do this? Have you tried it? If you did, you'd soon find out the answer.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Yes, by assigning a different Datatable to this variable.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to do this?

Answer : **No**

You can't access or use an object if it is null. You will get an [null reference exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx).

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.